# Calculating Center Of many blobs with aforge and manualy

Tags: c#, computer-vision, aforge

I'm trying to get the center of all detected blobs in an image, so I tried to do it in two different ways, and I got it two different results!
The first one is as follow:

```
        BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
        blobCounter.ObjectsOrder = ObjectsOrder.Area;
        blobCounter.ProcessImage(image);
        Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();
        AForge.Point Center = new AForge.Point();

        if (blobs.Length > 0)
        {
                Center.X = blobs.Average(c => c.CenterOfGravity.X);
                Center.Y = blobs.Average(c => c.CenterOfGravity.Y);
        }
```

and the second way is as follow:

```
        System.Drawing.Point Center = new System.Drawing.Point();
        int count = 0;
        int sumX = 0;
        int sumY = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ;i<image.Width;i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < image.Height; j++)
            {
                var p = image.GetPixel(i,j);
                if (!p.Name.ToLower().Equals("ff000000"))
                {
                    sumX += i;
                    sumY += j;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        if (count > 0)
        {
            Center.X = sumX / count;
            Center.Y = sumY / count;
        }
        return Center;
```

where

```
!p.Name.ToLower().Equals("ff000000")
```

means that the pixel is not black(i.e it's from some blob).
But what I don't understand why I get different result!
Can someone help me and tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking up exactly what the AForge method you're using does, I think the problem is that **The average of averages does not equal the average of their parts**.

E.g. I can take these numbers:

- 1
- 3
- 5
- 7
- 9

Together, their average is (1+3+5+7+9)/5=5. **But**, if I split the list into {5,3} (average 4) and {1,7,9} (average 5.66...), then take the average of {4, 5.66...}, I'll get something close to, but not equal to 5.

In this case, AForge's CenterOfGravity method is most likely returning the average position of the object which you are in turn averaging, while your own method is taking a single average of every part of every object.

Unrelated: Look into [Bitmap.LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits.aspx) for more efficient image operations.

Comment: I guess this is the problem, and I think more splitting means more difference between results! Right?